# Numpy shuffle multidimensional array by row only, keep column order unchanged

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

How can I shuffle a multidimensional array by row only in Python (so do not shuffle the columns).

**I am looking for the most efficient solution, because my matrix is very huge. Is it also possible to do this highly efficient on the original array (to save memory)?**

Example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.random((6, 2))
print(X)
Y = ???shuffle by row only not colls???
print(Y)
```

What I expect now is original matrix:

```
[[ 0.48252164  0.12013048]
 [ 0.77254355  0.74382174]
 [ 0.45174186  0.8782033 ]
 [ 0.75623083  0.71763107]
 [ 0.26809253  0.75144034]
 [ 0.23442518  0.39031414]]
```

Output shuffle the rows not cols e.g.:

```
[[ 0.45174186  0.8782033 ]
 [ 0.48252164  0.12013048]
 [ 0.77254355  0.74382174]
 [ 0.75623083  0.71763107]
 [ 0.23442518  0.39031414]
 [ 0.26809253  0.75144034]]
```

Comment: Option 1: shuffled view onto an array. I guess that would mean a custom implementation. (almost) no impact on memory usage, Obv. some impact at runtime. It really depends on how you **intend to use** this matrix.

Comment: Option 2: shuffle array in place. `np.random.shuffle(x)`, docs state that "this function only shuffles the array along the first index of a multi-dimensional array", which is good enough for you, right? Obv., some time taken at startup, but from that point, it's as fast as original matrix.

Comment: Compare to `np.random.shuffle(x)`, **shuffling index of nd-array and getting data from shuffled index** is more efficient way to solve this problem. For more details comparision refer my answer [bellow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646908/numpy-shuffle-multidimensional-array-by-row-only-keep-column-order-unchanged/43716153#43716153)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.shuffle()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html).

> This function only shuffles the array along the first axis of a
> multi-dimensional array. The order of sub-arrays is changed but their
> contents remains the same.

```
In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [3]:                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [3]: X = np.random.random((6, 2))                                                                                                                                                                        

In [4]: X                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: 
array([[0.71935047, 0.25796155],
       [0.4621708 , 0.55140423],
       [0.22605866, 0.61581771],
       [0.47264172, 0.79307633],
       [0.22701656, 0.11927993],
       [0.20117207, 0.2754544 ]])

In [5]: np.random.shuffle(X)                                                                                                                                                                                

In [6]: X                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: 
array([[0.71935047, 0.25796155],
       [0.47264172, 0.79307633],
       [0.4621708 , 0.55140423],
       [0.22701656, 0.11927993],
       [0.20117207, 0.2754544 ],
       [0.22605866, 0.61581771]])
```

For other functionalities you can also check out the following functions:

- [`random.Generator.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html#numpy.random.Generator.shuffle)
- [`random.Generator.permutation`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permutation.html)
- [`random.Generator.permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html)

The function `random.Generator.permuted` is introduced in Numpy's 1.20.0 Release.

> The new function differs from `shuffle` and `permutation` in that the
> subarrays indexed by an axis are permuted rather than the axis being
> treated as a separate 1-D array for every combination of the other
> indexes. For example, it is now possible to permute the rows or
> columns of a 2-D array.

Comment: I wonder if this could be sped up by numpy, maybe taking advantage of concurrency.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly I thinks this is the most available optimized approach in python. If you want to speed it up you need to make changes on algorithm.

Comment: I completely agree. I just realized that you are using `np.random` instead of the Python `random` module which also contains a shuffle function. I'm sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: This shuffle is not always working, see my new answer here below. Why is it not always working?

Comment: This method returns a `NoneType` object  - any solution for keeping the object a numpy array? **EDIT**: sorry all good: I had `X = np.random.shuffle(X)`, which returns a `NoneType` object, but the key was just `np.random.shuffle(X)`, since it is shuffled *in place*.

Comment: What about the labels Y. For example if I wanted to use this on a scikitlearn dataset. How would I get the labeled correctly shuffled to match?

Answer (score 30):

You can also use [`np.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) to generate random permutation of row indices and then index into the rows of `X` using [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) with `axis=0`. Also, `np.take` facilitates overwriting to the input array `X` itself with `out=` option, which would save us memory. Thus, the implementation would look like this -

```
np.take(X,np.random.permutation(X.shape[0]),axis=0,out=X)
```

Sample run -

```
In [23]: X
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0.60511059,  0.75001599],
       [ 0.30968339,  0.09162172],
       [ 0.14673218,  0.09089028],
       [ 0.31663128,  0.10000309],
       [ 0.0957233 ,  0.96210485],
       [ 0.56843186,  0.36654023]])

In [24]: np.take(X,np.random.permutation(X.shape[0]),axis=0,out=X);

In [25]: X
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0.14673218,  0.09089028],
       [ 0.31663128,  0.10000309],
       [ 0.30968339,  0.09162172],
       [ 0.56843186,  0.36654023],
       [ 0.0957233 ,  0.96210485],
       [ 0.60511059,  0.75001599]])
```

**Additional performance boost**

Here's a trick to speed up `np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])` with `np.argsort()` -

```
np.random.rand(X.shape[0]).argsort()
```

Speedup results -

```
In [32]: X = np.random.random((6000, 2000))

In [33]: %timeit np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 510 µs per loop

In [34]: %timeit np.random.rand(X.shape[0]).argsort()
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop
```

Thus, the shuffling solution could be modified to -

```
np.take(X,np.random.rand(X.shape[0]).argsort(),axis=0,out=X)
```

---

Runtime tests -

These tests include the two approaches listed in this post and `np.shuffle` based one in [`@Kasramvd's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646937/3293881).

```
In [40]: X = np.random.random((6000, 2000))

In [41]: %timeit np.random.shuffle(X)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.2 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit np.take(X,np.random.permutation(X.shape[0]),axis=0,out=X)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.3 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit np.take(X,np.random.rand(X.shape[0]).argsort(),axis=0,out=X)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.2 ms per loop
```

So, it seems using these `np.take` based could be used only if memory is a concern or else `np.random.shuffle` based solution looks like the way to go.

Comment: This sounds nice. Can you add a timing information to your post, of your np.take v.s. standard shuffle? The np.shuffle on my system is faster (27.9ms) vs your take (62.9 ms), but as I read in your post, there is a memory advantage?

Comment: @robert Just added, check it out!

Answer (score 13):

After a bit of experiment (i) found the most memory and time-efficient way to shuffle data(row-wise)in an nD array. First, shuffle the index of an array then, use the shuffled index to get the data. e.g.

```
rand_num2 = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
perm = np.arange(rand_num2.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(perm)
rand_num2 = rand_num2[perm]
```

**in more details**
Here, I am using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to find memory usage and python's builtin "time" module to record time and comparing all previous answers

```
def main():
    # shuffle data itself
    rand_num = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
    start = time.time()
    np.random.shuffle(rand_num)
    print('Time for direct shuffle: {0}'.format((time.time() - start)))
    
    # Shuffle index and get data from shuffled index
    rand_num2 = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
    start = time.time()
    perm = np.arange(rand_num2.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(perm)
    rand_num2 = rand_num2[perm]
    print('Time for shuffling index: {0}'.format((time.time() - start)))
    
    # using np.take()
    rand_num3 = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
    start = time.time()
    np.take(rand_num3, np.random.rand(rand_num3.shape[0]).argsort(), axis=0, out=rand_num3)
    print("Time taken by np.take, {0}".format((time.time() - start)))
```

**Result for Time**

```
Time for direct shuffle: 0.03345608711242676   # 33.4msec
Time for shuffling index: 0.019818782806396484 # 19.8msec
Time taken by np.take, 0.06726956367492676     # 67.2msec
```

**Memory profiler Result**

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    39  117.422 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    40                             def main():
    41                                 # shuffle data itself
    42  208.977 MiB   91.555 MiB       rand_num = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
    43  208.977 MiB    0.000 MiB       start = time.time()
    44  208.977 MiB    0.000 MiB       np.random.shuffle(rand_num)
    45  208.977 MiB    0.000 MiB       print('Time for direct shuffle: {0}'.format((time.time() - start)))
    46                             
    47                                 # Shuffle index and get data from shuffled index
    48  300.531 MiB   91.555 MiB       rand_num2 = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
    49  300.531 MiB    0.000 MiB       start = time.time()
    50  300.535 MiB    0.004 MiB       perm = np.arange(rand_num2.shape[0])
    51  300.539 MiB    0.004 MiB       np.random.shuffle(perm)
    52  300.539 MiB    0.000 MiB       rand_num2 = rand_num2[perm]
    53  300.539 MiB    0.000 MiB       print('Time for shuffling index: {0}'.format((time.time() - start)))
    54                             
    55                                 # using np.take()
    56  392.094 MiB   91.555 MiB       rand_num3 = np.random.randint(5, size=(6000, 2000))
    57  392.094 MiB    0.000 MiB       start = time.time()
    58  392.242 MiB    0.148 MiB       np.take(rand_num3, np.random.rand(rand_num3.shape[0]).argsort(), axis=0, out=rand_num3)
    59  392.242 MiB    0.000 MiB       print("Time taken by np.take, {0}".format((time.time() - start)))
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code that produce this output?

Comment: i lost the code to produce [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) output. But it can be very easily reproduced by following steps in the given link.

Comment: What I like about this answer is that if I have two matched arrays (which coincidentally I do) then I can shuffle both of them and ensure that data in corresponding positions still match. This is useful for randomising the order of my training set

Answer (score 8):

I tried many solutions, and at the end I used this simple one:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
x = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6]])
print(shuffle(x, random_state=0))
```

output:

```
[
[5 6]  
[3 4]  
[1 2]
]
```

if you have 3d array, loop through the 1st axis (axis=0) and apply this function, like:

```
np.array([shuffle(item) for item in 3D_numpy_array])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can shuffle a two dimensional array `A` **by row** using the `np.vectorize()` function:

```
shuffle = np.vectorize(np.random.permutation, signature='(n)->(n)')

A_shuffled = shuffle(A)
```